# How can I restrict to called my function 2 times

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

```
<div *ngFor="let ticket of filteredTickets | orderBy : 'ResolvedAt';let i = index;" (click)="showTicketDetail(ticket)">
    <div>
        <a >{{ticket.value.IssueNo}}</a>
        <a class="checkbox" (click)="resolvedAndUnResolvedAction($event,ticket.value);">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mark-resolve{{i}}" [checked]="!helper.empty(ticket.value.ResolvedAt)" />
            <label for="mark-resolve{{i}}">Mark as resolved</label>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code and when I click on checkbox the click function is going to call two times, Is there any why to restrict that click on two time, 
I have used this in function:

```
resolvedAndUnResolvedAction(event, issue) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   console.log('called');
}
```

This will print called 2 times in console

Comment: try `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @akinjide ok let me try that

Comment: try using counter and put condition if it calls second time simple navigate it to elsewhere

Comment: That not proper solutions bro @Rao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let ticket of filteredTickets | orderBy : 'ResolvedAt';let i = index;" (click)="showTicketDetail(ticket)">
    <div>
        <a >{{ticket.value.IssueNo}}</a>
        <a class="checkbox" (click)="resolvedAndUnResolvedAction($event,ticket.value);">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mark-resolve{{i}}" [checked]="!helper.empty(ticket.value.ResolvedAt)" />
            <label (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" for="mark-resolve{{i}}">Mark as resolved</label>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just added **(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"** in label that works for me

Answer (score 0):

> Its not just matter to stop calling the twice the method. The aim should be why is it calling twice ?

### 1.

How could you say its calling twice ? Are you checking log and telling. Did you put the same log in any other method ?

### 2.

Are you calling the same method from its parent component as well, which is trigger this again.

### 3.

Is there any kind of nested call of method ?

Comment: I have called this function only once, & get that log twice in console

Comment: For debugging, call this method out of the ngFor loop and check it still calling twice.